# Stack Too Deep error with only 5 items on stack

Tags: solidity, error, stack

So, there are a lot of these questions and I've read through a bunch of them and several blog posts, but I'm still stumped on why I'm getting the error here.

My function (to reproduce, copy it to [here](https://remix.ethereum.org/#optimize=true&runs=1000&evmVersion=null&version=soljson-v0.5.17+commit.d19bba13.js)):

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.1;
contract stacktest{
    function stackdeep(address v1, uint v2, uint v3, uint v4, uint v5, uint v6, uint v7, uint v8) public view returns(uint[8] memory){
        uint v9=0;
        uint[8] memory args;
        uint v10=v8;
        uint v11 =v8;
        uint v12=v5;
        uint v13=v5;
        args[1]=v13;
        args[2]=v12;
        args[3]=v3;
        args[4]=v6;
        args[5]=v7;
        args[6]=v10;
        args[7]=v11;
        bytes memory v14=abi.encodePacked(v13);
        bytes32 v15=keccak256(v14);
        args[0]=uint(v1); //<= This line is where remix gives me a Stack Too Deep error
        return(args);
    }
}
```

If I comment out the problematic line to get it to compile and debug a transaction (with v1="0x1111111111111111111111111111111111111111" and v2-v8 = 2-8), when I reach that line the stack shows this:

```
[
    "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002a5",
    "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002",
    "0x0000000000000000000000001111111111111111111111111111111111111111",
    "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000180",
    "0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006916a24e"
]
```

So the variable I want (v1) is in the 3rd position on the stack and there are a total of 5 items on the stack.  How would adding this to the array cause a Stack Too Deep error?

Edit:
While trying to fix this, I hit a different stack error that confuses me.  This time the error is occurring on this function definition line, so I'm not sure how to debug it.  How would a function that takes 1 array and returns 1 array have a stack issue on the function definition?

```
function stackdeep2(bytes memory data) public returns(uint[8] memory){//<= This is the line that shows the error.
        uint v9=0;
        (address v1, uint v2, uint v3, uint v4, uint v5, uint v6, uint v7, uint v8)=abi.decode(data,(address,uint,uint,uint,uint,uint,uint,uint));
        uint[8] memory args;
        uint v10=v8;
        uint v11=v8;
        uint v12=v5;
        uint v13=v5;

        bytes memory v14=abi.encodePacked(v13);
        bytes32 v15=keccak256(v14);
        //args[0]=uint(v1);
        return(args);
    }
```

Comment: I remember I was trying to read through an article explaining how accessing the stack in different places causes the error, but it got quite complicated and I simply gave up and decided "it's magic".

Comment: The EVM has some opcodes DUP1-DUP16 and SWAP1-SWAP16 that operate over the topmost elements in the stack.

The EVM is stack based, so any operations will use the stack to temporarily store data for processing.

Also local variables are stored in the stack, because it is cheaper. If you have too many local variables, or a complex interaction it will cause a stack too deep, because the compiler requires an opcode that doesn't exists, like DUP17 or SWAP18.

Comment: @Ismael How would it require DUP17 or SWAP18 to add the third item to an array when there are 5 items on the stack?

Comment: @KalevMaricq I haven't tried yet but I'm guessing that either remix hide part of the stack or solc don't generate the whole stack until you need it, ie when you use v1 it generate the code with v1 on the stack. Did you try if enabling optimization changes something?